# Detecting "one-tabbed" browsers in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect browsers with only one tab in javascript?

We have some features which are opening links in a new tab, and some of the mobile devices are ignoring those links when opening in facebook, instagram, twitter or slack embeded browsers, since it can't open it in new tab because it is one tab browser?

So far, we are using user agent for detection, but i would like to know is it possible to detect something "tab" related.

```
this.isFacebookBrowser = function (params) {

            var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
            return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);
        };
```

Comment: `userAgent` seems like the way to go. But I would have an array of all the excluded browsers and check if any of them exist in `userAgent`.

Comment: I don’t see any way to properly detect this. The Navigator object doesn’t seem to expose that info in any way, so the most you could do is try to open a new tab using `window.open`, and try to draw your conclusions from the return value … but you can’t do that automatically, without proper user interaction, because then popup blockers will catch it. If your links are using `target="_blank"` to open in a new tab, I guess you could append that with a click handler that uses window.open instead, and at least then be able to check if that worked after the fact …

Comment: There might be a way to open the native browser from an anchor tag. In this case, you could approximate the user agent device like you're doing now and depending on that outcome modify an anchor accordingly. Not sure what support for this looks like across browser and hardware though.